# Repeated measures design: Must each participant receive ALL 4 versions of a given stimulus?

Tags: repeated-measures, experiment-design, latin-square

I am creating a 2x2 repeated measures design where a given stimulus object has four possible versions (2 factors with 2 levels each create 4 unique object versions). In the ideal repeated measures design, a subject receives all 4 versions of every object, but I am concerned about the unintended effect of object familiarity with 4 exposures to versions of the same object. Is it possible to divide participants into X groups, giving each group only 2 of the 4 possible conditions for a given object? With multiple stimulus objects, the number of conditions sampled across objects would balance out.

Grateful for any insight into the benefits or pitfalls of this modification!

Comment: It all depends on what you are attempting to measure and the end result of the experiment.  If you don't want to have each subject repeating the given stimulus and there is not the possibility of getting more subjects, then maybe a Balanced Incomplete Block design is a possibility.